# How to launch the configuration activity from widget?

Tags: android, android-intent, configuration, widget, preferenceactivity

**On this question are not answers in all over internet, I not found. I spent all my day on searces, so I start to think, that nobody knows**

Im new on stackoverflow and English is not my native lang. So, sorry for my bad English.

Ok, here is a question. I creating a simple widget with 2 buttons. One of there button may launch config.activity by on clicking it.
How I can do it?
Im try with Intent, as here:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, ConfigActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(i);
```

But when I receive the intent action I see next situation: config.activity quickly start and close, because the appWidgetId is not valid.

How to launch the configuration activity from widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating from Provider class, fetch the widget id from onUpdate() method, like this:

```
final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
   int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
}
```

or if your updating widget from ConfigurationActivity, fetch the widget id from  onCreate method like this:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
```

Make your widget lauch ConfigurationActivity from a button/imageview in your widget_layout

```
    // Create intent pointing to ConfigurationActivity, in this example we are at ConfigurationActivity
    Intent configurationIntent = new Intent(WidgetBarConfiguration.this, WidgetBarConfiguration.class);
    // Create a extra giving the App Widget Id
    configurationIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    // Create a pending intent giving configurationIntent as parameter
    PendingIntent configurationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(WidgetBarConfiguration.this, 0, configurationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Here we fecth the layout item and give it a action
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(WidgetBarConfiguration.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_bar_layout);
    // Setting onClick event that will lauch ConfigurationActivity
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageViewSettings, configurationPendingIntent);
    // Updating widget
    mWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    finish();
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".WidgetBarConfiguration"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_widget_configuration"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Look that `lauchMode = "singleInstance"` will make sure only the ConfigurationActivity layout appear on clicked, without any other activity layout attached.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Intent launchActivity = new Intent(context, ConfigActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchActivity, 0);
        titles.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button, pendingIntent);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, rv);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand, where it must be placed? And I think, your code is wrong or code is not full. And one note: it must send WidgetID to configurity activity, because config activity just receiving and check it on valid, after returns result OK or Canceled